# Gitlab Issue: Commit is not signed

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner, gitlab-ce

```
Getting source from Git repository
Fetching changes with git depth set to 20...
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /home/younes/Desktop/builds/PczuNw7zp/0/root/test/.git/
Checking out c2f1a8f3 as detached HEAD (ref is main)...
Skipping Git submodules setup
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
$ /home/younes/Desktop/script.sh
Commit is not signed
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
```

Comment: Please post the error as a text, and not an image.

Comment: What is script.sh?

Comment: @eyllanesc is a  the script  I am putting in config.toml  as well as in .gitlab-ci.yml

Comment: please provide a [mre]